# Sort DataFrame columns according to value in [last row, first column]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df and I am trying to sort the columns in descending order based on the value in the last row (basically the value in the most left, down cell in the df).
How can I do that in Python?

I have tried to search for a similar problem to mine but I have not managed to find a solution.

Thank you.

The resulting df should have in cell df[-1,1] the greatest value in the row, in df[-1,2] the second greatest...and so on.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `argsort()` on the negative values of the relevant row for this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df.iloc[:,np.argsort(-df.iloc[-1,:])]
```

Comment: I wanted to post nearly the same, but the negative values part in your answer is more elegant. Nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is you're trying to sort data based on the last column. I imagine this last column would be dynamic so you can't just use the column's name. For sorting any dataframe in descending order, you can use

```
df.sort_values([column name], ascending=False)
```

for finding the last column, you can use

```
df.columns[-1]
```

Putting that together, I think you want something like this.

```
df.sort_values(df.columns[-1], ascending=False)
```